# Export the project in Eclipse without including the third party jars

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have to build a jar by exporting my project. I used some third party jars / APIs in my project. I have added them to my build path.

Now I have to exclude those third party jars and build my jar. I tried removing them from build path but my jar isn't working properly.

Comment: I don't think this question gives much of an account of what has been done (e.g. on the command line) so am voting to close as not containing enough detail.

Comment: @halfer There is a certain way you add jars to dependencies in Eclipse. I'm voting to leave this as clear enough.

Comment: It is almost definitely a duplicate though.

Comment: @Basilevs, I'm happy for it to be closed as a dup instead. As it stands this Q/A pair don't shed much light on the topic, and I'd guess since there's not much to respond to, new answers are unlikely now. It's good to trim old material if it doesn't offer much long-term value, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

In the export dialog, there is an option "Library handling". Choose "Copy required libraries into a subfolder...", instead of extracting or packaging.

Comment: But I am getting NoClassDefFound Exception. How the jar will take those while running from the lib folder...!!?

Comment: You need to add the jar directoy to the classpath: java -cp jarFileDir JavaClass.